# Busca retorna apenas a home do site

Tags: wordpress

Criei os arquivos `search.php` e `searchform.php` para um tema de WordPress que estou desenvolvendo. Porém ao testar a busca ela não retorna nada, mostrando apenas a página inicial.

Eu havia escrito uma consulta diferente do padrão em um outro tema de um projeto antigo e nesse tema ele funciona normalmente, mas no meu atual projeto ocorre esse erro. Os códigos são os seguintes:

*searchform.php*

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" id="searchform" role="search">
    <input type="text" id="campo_busca" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>"></input>
    <input id="button_busca" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

*search.php*

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>
    <div class="content">
      <section id="conteudo_pagina">
        <p id="tempobusca"><?php $mySearch = & new WP_Query("s=$s & showposts=20"); $num = $mySearch->post_count; echo $num.' resultados de pesquisa para '; the_search_query();?> em <?php  get_num_queries(); ?> <?php timer_stop(1); ?> segundos.</p>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="box internas">
              <div class="cabecalho">
                <h2>BUSCA</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="linha_pesquisa">
              <li>
                <article>
                    <p class="titulobusca"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link permanente para <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <p class="excertobusca"><?php the_content_rss('more_link_text', TRUE, '', 30); ?></p>
                </article>
              </li>
            </ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div id="paginacao">
                <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
                    <?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="maisantigos"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Mais antigos','arclite')) ?></div>
                    <div class="maisrecentes"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Mais recentes &raquo;','arclite')) ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php else:?>
            <ul id="linha_pesquisa">
              <li>
                <article>
                    <h3>404 - NOT FOUND</h3>
                    <h4>Post não encontrado</h4>
                    <p>Desculpe, mas o texto que você procura não está aqui.</p>
                </article>
              </li>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </section>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei porque está usando uma *page template* quando o padrão é que o theme tenha um [arquivo `search.php` dedicado](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) a mostrar os resultados da busca. Comparando seu código com o [Twenty Eleven](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven) vejo que o `searchform.php` tem os seguintes problemas:

- `bloginfo()` está deprecado, se ligar o `WP_DEBUG` verá o aviso. Use

  ```
   action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
  ```
- você definiu o `field` de search como `name="busca"`, mas está procurando por `s=$s` no seu `search.php`

Não testei criar uma page template para `search.php` e na verdade desconfio que uma coisa assim pode criar conflitos, o ideal seria `page-search.php` e configurar o que for necessário pra isso funcionar. Usando o [`search.php` padrão](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyeleven/1.8/search.php) funciona.

Seu `search.php` tem um `&` sobrando em:

```
$mySearch = & new WP_Query("s=
```

Isso faz saltar um aviso de:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in [...]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Fiz as correções e a busca voltou a funcionar.